# **TypeError: 'module' object is not callable** - uwsgi - flask - python

Tags: python, uwsgi

This is my file structure:

```
|--cm
|  |--bin
|  |--include
|  |--lib
|  |--app
|  |  |--views.py
|  |  |--all Flask webapp folders
|  |--uwsgi.ini
|  |--run.py
```

run.py

```
from app import views

if __name__ == "__main__":
    views.application.run()
```

part of views.py:

```
application = Flask(__name__)
application.debug = True
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
processes = 1
socket = /var/www/KRAKEN/public/cm/socket.sock
chmod-socket = 666
plugin = python
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name server.me www.server.me;
        root /var/www/KRAKEN/public/;
        error_log /var/www/KRAKEN/public/nginx.error.log;
        location / {
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

    location /cm {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /cm;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///var/www/KRAKEN/public/cm/socket.sock;
    }

}
```

When i run

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini -w run
```

I get:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (32bit) on [Mon Mar 14 15:45:13 2016] ***
compiled with version: 5.3.0 on 11 March 2016 01:01:30
os: Linux-3.14.58-1-ARCH #1 SMP Fri Dec 11 18:21:13 MST 2015
nodename: KRAKEN
machine: armv7l
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /var/www/KRAKEN/public/cm
detected binary path: /var/www/KRAKEN/public/cm/bin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 14019
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
*** RRDtool library available at 0x1eebe58 ***
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address socket.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.5.1 (default, Mar  6 2016, 10:14:04)  [GCC 5.3.0]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1efa768
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 128512 bytes (125 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 2 seconds on interpreter 0x1efa768 pid: 32487 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 32487)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 32489, cores: 1)
```

Then i go to the app route and get:

```
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

I believe there is something wrong with the **callable**, tried setting callable = views or callabe = app.views as shown in Flask(**name**) but with no success.

The NGINX error log throws:

```
2016/03/14 17:19:22 [error] 1434#0: *355 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 190.228.175.122, server: server.me, request: "GET /cm/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///var/www/KRAKEN/public/cm/socket.sock:", host: "www.server.me"
```

Tips?

EDIT: actually, changing callable = views rendered another error:

**TypeError: 'module' object is not callable**

Which now I belive is a more python related issue...

Edit2: i'm running under a virtual env.

Edit3: just to clarify, the app does work when run with **python run.py**.

Edit4: detail when i run the uwsgi command.

Edit5: nginx info.

Comment: Your callable *isn't* `app.views`, it appears to be `app.views.application`

Comment: @Suever Thanks for your time. Changed callable to that and same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved views.py out of cm to the app root dir and worked.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution to this answer is instead of running and troubleshooting

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini -w run
```

Is to instead debug the errors you get from run.py.  Give this a shot and resolve any issues -

```
python run.py
```

Flask is giving you this TypeError because whatever file that is following this pattern:

```
from app import views

if __name__ == "__main__":
    views.application.run()
```

has an issue and wouldn't run with or without UWSGI. UWSGI is hiding the real root cause behind a TypeError.